# Updating a RichTextBox with many UI-access operations

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a sub-classed RichTextBox that I use to display chat information scrubbed from a game. Each chat line is saved into a custom object that stores the text as well as some meta-data. The RTB then uses this meta data to do some formatting. Here's the relevant code section:

```
public class ChatLine
{   //stub-class with code irrelevant to the question removed
    public string Text { get; set; };
    public Color Color { get; set; };
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; };
    public string Name { get; set; };   //name of the player where this text originated
}

public partial class CustomRichTextbox : RichTextBox
{
    private readonly Object syncRoot = new();

    private readonly List<ChatLine> displayedChatLines = new(); 
    internal IReadOnlyCollection<ChatLine> DisplayedChatLines
    {
        get
        {
            return displayedChatLines.AsReadOnly();
        }
    }

    public CustomRichTextbox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Appends text to the current text of the textbox, ends the line, and returns the first line position that was appended.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The second parameter should be supplied if you want to enable name display per line, and supplying the name you don't want displayed.
    /// </remarks>
    internal int AppendLines(IEnumerable<ChatLine> lines, string name = "")
    {
        //when the RTB is empty line count will be 0, which is what we should return
        //when the RTB is not empty then we need to return line count - 1
        //the Math.Max call ensures we take care of both cases
        var pos = Math.Max(0, Lines.Length - 1);

        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            base.AppendText(String.Join(String.Empty, lines.Select(FormatLine)));
            displayedChatLines.AddRange(lines);
        }

        //paint the lines after we append (THIS LOOP IS TIME CONSUMING)
        for (int i = lines.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var index = pos + i;
            var line = displayedChatLines[index];
            var start = this.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(index);
            var timestampEnd = this.Find(">", start, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
            var textStart = timestampEnd + 2;
            var lineLength = this.Lines[index].Length;

            //color in timestamp
            this.Select(start, timestampEnd - start + 1);
            this.SelectionColor = this.ForeColor;
            this.SelectionBackColor = this.BackColor;
            this.SelectionFont = this.Font;
            this.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || name == line.Name)
            {   //line doesn't contain name
                this.Select(textStart, start + lineLength - textStart + 1);
                this.SelectionColor = line.Color;
                this.SelectionBackColor = (line.Color == Color.White) ? Color.DarkGray : this.BackColor;
            }
            else
            {   //line contains name
                var nameStart = this.Find($" {line.Name}", start, start + lineLength, RichTextBoxFinds.Reverse);
                this.Select(textStart, nameStart - textStart);
                this.SelectionColor = line.Color;
                this.SelectionBackColor = (line.Color == Color.White) ? Color.DarkGray : this.BackColor;

                this.Select(nameStart, start + lineLength - nameStart + 1);
                this.SelectionColor = Color.DarkGray;
                this.SelectionBackColor = this.BackColor;
                this.SelectionFont = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, 8);
                this.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;    //this actually causes the entire line to be right aligned
            }
        }

        this.DeselectAll(); //necessary otherwise restoring scroll position won't work

        return pos;

        string FormatLine(ChatLine line)
        {
            return (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || name == line.Name) ? 
                $"<{line.Timestamp: hh:mm:ss tt}> {line.Text}{Environment.NewLine}" :
                $"<{line.Timestamp: hh:mm:ss tt}> {line.Text} {line.Name}{Environment.NewLine}";
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine...for updates that have few lines. When it needs to update more (say 1000) the UI thread chokes up for a few seconds to do all the painting. I've identified the time-consuming code (noted in the code above) because when I comment that loop out then there's no problem.

Normally I'd just move the time-consuming code to a backgroundworker or use an async/await pattern, but the problem is all the code that's in the time consuming section requires UI-thread access! What do I do when I can't push the time-consuming stuff to another thread?

Comment: when you make a separate thread and you want to access `cross-thread` controls and properties you can use `BeginInvoke` if necessary to grant access. also the only way I can think of to get rid of the UI freezing is using another thread or using async/await ways.

Comment: Never do this: `var lineLength = this.Lines[index].Length;`. Don't ever use the `Lines` property when you have performance / responsiveness requirements. Also, it's not needed at all.

Comment: @Jimi Actually you were right on point. After I optimized the loop to avoid calling `Lines.Length` I saw a huge performance gain. If you want to write up an answer then I can accept it.

Comment: I'll post some notes tomorrow.